# MYSQL grabbing DISTINCT row from 3 different fields

Tags: mysql

Hi how would I change this query so that it outputs distinct results. I need to do 3 queries one for `ios`, `roid`, and if both `ios & roid` are `NULL`... based on the `u.sacid` and grabbing the newest listed determine by `last_login` (date). if all 3 can be combined into one query that would be great. Tricky part is user 0101 can have an entry for IOS and then another row the same user 0101 can have an droid entry.

right now my query just grabs everything, and I filter with PHP ... a lot more code and not efficient.

```
$sql = "select ur.user_id, u.sacid, u.fname, u.lname, u.email, u.last_login, ur.role_id, 
        r.name as role_name, i.device_token AS ios, dg.group_name, dg.ad_group, 
        a.device_token AS roid
        FROM users AS u
        inner join user_roles AS ur on u.id = ur.user_id
        inner join roles AS r on ur.role_id = r.id
        left outer join ios_tokens AS i on u.sacid = i.sacf_id
        left outer join roid_tokens AS a on u.sacid = a.sacf_id
        left outer join board_groups AS dg on dg.role_id = r.id
        order by u.email asc";
```

**Result current Output**

```
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| user_id | sacid   | fname | lname | email        | last_login          | role_id | role_name | ios       | group_name | ad_group | roid     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 313     | p139k3l | John  | Doe   | john@doe.com | 2018-09-24 16:23:46 | 6       | ops       | NULL      | MainDevice | Offser   | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 313     | p139k3l | John  | Doe   | john@doe.com | 2018-09-24 16:15:46 | 6       | ops       | NULL      | MainDevice | Offser   | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 303     | m2363   | Scot  | Do    | Jane@do.com  | 2018-09-14 13:43:33 | 6       | ops       | fSerXerer | Sites      | FS2      | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 303     | m2363   | Scot  | Do    | Jane@do.com  | 2018-09-14 13:23:33 | 6       | ops       | NULL      | Ops        | IFS      | UxAG_IFS |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 163     | m5217   | Val   | Baa   | Val@baa.com  | 2018-06-13 17:31:20 | 6       | ops       | CSerde    | ICOM       | COM_SITE | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| user_id | sacid   | fname | lname | email        | last_login          | role_id | role_name | ios       | group_name | ad_group | roid     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 313     | p139k3l | John  | Doe   | john@doe.com | 2018-09-24 16:23:46 | 6       | ops       | NULL      | MainDevice | Offser   | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 303     | m2363   | Scot  | Do    | Jane@do.com  | 2018-09-14 13:43:33 | 6       | ops       | fSerXerer | Sites      | FS2      | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 303     | m2363   | Scot  | Do    | Jane@do.com  | 2018-09-14 13:23:33 | 6       | ops       | NULL      | Ops        | IFS      | UxAG_IFS |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| 163     | m5217   | Val   | Baa   | Val@baa.com  | 2018-06-13 17:31:20 | 6       | ops       | CSerde    | ICOM       | COM_SITE | NULL     |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: could you please add sample input and output ?

Comment: Please explain why using 'DISTINCT' in the query won't do what you want. What columns need to be distinct?

Comment: no idea, the description blows my mind... I need to see some data (per table, NOT the query output) AND then show us what the result should be. **sample data** and **expected result** , nothing else works as well

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Added sample results of current query

Comment: can you please provide your expected output in table structure @acctman

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I can not say that it won't ... if one query can scan grab IOS , droid and if both are NULL then that would be great.

Comment: @fa06 added desired output

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. your requirement is not seems to be clear

Comment: Your sample data set is unnecessarily complicated. It's off-putting.

Comment: Did you try the union query?

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison No luck... I ran the query and it still had duplicates in it

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct

```
$sql = "select distinct ur.user_id, u.sacid, u.fname, u.lname, u.email, u.last_login, ur.role_id, 
        r.name as role_name, i.device_token AS ios, dg.group_name, dg.ad_group, 
        a.device_token AS roid
        FROM users AS u
        inner join user_roles AS ur on u.id = ur.user_id
        inner join roles AS r on ur.role_id = r.id
        left outer join ios_tokens AS i on u.sacid = i.sacf_id
        left outer join roid_tokens AS a on u.sacid = a.sacf_id
        left outer join board_groups AS dg on dg.role_id = r.id
        order by u.email asc";
```

Comment: Result is the same as current... with Distinct added